# Cakephp How to order by date and month only

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a contact table with date field for birthdate.

Now I would like to show list of birthday within next week. I can show it, but the order is based on the year.

How can I order the data, just based on month and day only?

```
$sideBarTaskSuggestion = 
$this->Project->Contact->find('all', array(
   'conditions' => array(
      'Contact.group_id' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.group_id'),
      'Contact.birthdate NOT' => null,
      'AND' => array(
           array('Contact.birthdate NOT' => null),
           array('Contact.birthdate + INTERVAL EXTRACT(YEAR FROM NOW()) - 
              EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Contact.birthdate) YEAR <=' => date('Y-m-d', 
                 strtotime('+1 week'))),
           array('Contact.birthdate + INTERVAL EXTRACT(YEAR FROM NOW()) -
              EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Contact.birthdate) YEAR >=' => date('Y-m-d')),
      )
    ),
   'order' => 'Contact.birthdate DESC'
)
);
```

Comment: Does anyone besides me not bother reading the question when there is a requirement for horizontal scrolling?

Comment: Did you try doing the same thing you do in your 'AND' conditions? Specifically: `'order' => 'EXTRACT(MONTH from Contact.birthdate) DESC'`

Comment: @DanBracuk fix the horizontal scroll bar

Comment: @iso27002 I tried does not work

Comment: Any error message? Because I know in pure SQL you can do `select * from contacts AS Contact order by EXTRACT(MONTH from Contact.birthdate)` so I guess the question is: what does Cake translate the `'order' => 'EXTRACT(...)'` to

Comment: @iso27002 no error message, it is still sorted, but it's not in the correct order. I tried you SQL query, and I still get the wrong order for 1 date. this is the result of the query from top to bottom : "1987-03-27, 1989-06-19, 1984-06-24, 1989-11-25, 2013-11-26, 1990-11-28, 1989-12-01, 1989-12-03, 1989-12-04, 1989-12-02" If you see the date, everything seems in order regardless the year.. until the last date become out of order (this is pure SQL) from phpmyadmin

Comment: The query I gave you groups only by month, so it works properly. Try this: `select * from contacts AS Contact order by EXTRACT(MONTH from Contact.birthdate) DESC, EXTRACT(DAY from Contact.birthdate) DESC;`

Comment: @iso27002 I see, yes it's working now in SQL. I guess I need to try 2 use 2 sorting in cakephp

Comment: Upvoted for editing the question to take away horizontal scrolling.  Now that I am reading the question, I am curious about why ordering by the entire date is unsatisfactory.

Comment: If the Cake `'order' => 'EXTRACT(..)'` worked, and the missing day ordering is the only problem, try this: `'order' => array('EXTRACT(MONTH from Contact.birthdate) DESC','EXTRACT(DAY from Contact.birthdate) DESC')` - that should work. // edit: TIL about DAYOFYEAR()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say you want 'order the data, just based on month and day only?', I assume you mean:

- Nov 22, 2013
- Oct 21, 1922
- Mar 5, 2000
- Jan 31, 2001
- Jan 1, 1990

Then try this:
`'order' => 'DAYOFYEAR(Contact.birthdate) DESC'`

Comment: Is above query for finding birthday within upcoming 1 week? What if I want to change to upcoming 1 month? Kindly share

Comment: @AadityaBhatt - My answer is how the results are ordered. You need to change the `conditions` array to change which data is returned.